# What's the best way to pass and retrieve data from a child form component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

This is my current method:

**Parent.vue:**

```
// Template

<form-child :schema="schema"><form-child>

// JS

data () {
  return {
    schema: [{ // name: '', value: '', type: '' }, { //etc ... }]
  }
}
```

**FormChild.vue**:

```
// Template

<div v-for="field in schema">
  <input v-if="field.type === 'text'" @change="updateValue(field.name, field.value)">
  <textarea v-if="field.type === 'textarea'" @change="updateValue(field.name, field.value)">/textarea>
</div>

// JS

props: {
  schema: Arrary
}

methods: {
  updateValue (fieldName, fieldValue) {
    this.schema.forEach(field => {
      // this makes schema update in Parent.vue
      if (field.name === fieldName) field.value = fieldValue
    })
  }
}
```

Is this the optimal way? Or maybe there's a better one using `emit` and `v-model`? (If so, could you provide a sample code?)

Comment: if you are running vue in dev mode it should actually throw warnings here. You should not manupulate props directly. only change the data where "it was defined". You should emit on the child and listen to it in the parent.

Comment: Use `$emit` and `$on`. This is well documented [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events) .

Comment: @RoyJ I updated the question. There are `v-if`'s.

Comment: @FrankProvost There won't be a warning because I'm mutating the values inside an array/objects.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events
As many users mentionned, use `$emit` and `$on` to pass data between parents and childs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A properly encapsulated child component would be decoupled from the parent data structure. It would take `type` and `value` as separate props, plus an opaque `id` to tell the parent which value the component is emitting about.

By making a settable computed based on the `value` parameter, the component can use `v-model` on its form elements. The `set` function emits an `input` event with the `id` and the `newValue`, and the parent takes it from there.

**Update**: I decided I didn't like the `id` going to the component, so I handled that in the input handler: `@input="updateField(index, $event)`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    schema: [{
        type: 'text',
        name: 'one',
        value: "1"
      },
      {
        type: 'textarea',
        name: 'two',
        value: "stuff in the textarea"
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    updateField(index, newValue) {
      this.schema[index].value = newValue;
    }
  },
  components: {
    formInput: {
      props: ['type', 'value'],
      computed: {
        proxyValue: {
          get() { return this.value; },
          set(newValue) {
            this.$emit('input', newValue);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="field in schema">
    {{field.name}} = {{field.value}}
  </div>
  <form-input inline-template v-for="field, index in schema" :type="field.type" :key="index" :value="field.value" @input="updateField(index, $event)">
    <div>
      <input v-if="type === 'text'" v-model="proxyValue">
      <textarea v-if="type === 'textarea'" v-model="proxyValue"></textarea>
    </div>
  </form-input>
</div>
```

Comment: Beautiful implementation. Thanks.

Comment: One question: why didn't you want to pass a schema like `:schema="schema"`? Because for each field I add to the objects inside schema I'd have to create a new prop.

Comment: You only need to pass to the child the props it will actually use. You pass `type` and `value` because the child uses them. It does not use `name`, and might not use others you add.

Answer (score 1):

For what you are doing here, there is no need to separate the form into a component. Just make it part of the parent and use `v-model`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    schema: [{
        type: 'text',
        name: 'one',
        value: "1"
      },
      {
        type: 'textarea',
        name: 'two',
        value: "stuff in the textarea"
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="field in schema">
    {{field.name}} = {{field.value}}
  </div>
  <div v-for="field in schema">
    <input v-if="field.type === 'text'" v-model="field.value">
    <textarea v-if="field.type === 'textarea'" v-model="field.value"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want the component for reusability and you don't care about insulating the parent from changes (best practice is not to have anything outside a component change its data), you can just wrap the same thing in a component:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    schema: [{
        type: 'text',
        name: 'one',
        value: "1"
      },
      {
        type: 'textarea',
        name: 'two',
        value: "stuff in the textarea"
      }
    ]
  },
  components: {
    formChild: {
      props: ['value']
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="field in schema">
    {{field.name}} = {{field.value}}
  </div>
  <form-child inline-template v-model="schema">
    <div>
      <div v-for="field in value">
        <input v-if="field.type === 'text'" v-model="field.value">
        <textarea v-if="field.type === 'textarea'" v-model="field.value"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form-child>
</div>
```